# Dynamically adding controls to a panel multiple times and get their values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have three dropdown lists in a panel and I want to add this panel again and again, later on I want to get the selected values.

```html
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ucEducation.ascx.cs" 
                ClassName="aaa" Inherits="ucEducation" %>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>Degree (required)<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDegree" 
                 class="form-control" required runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>College (required)<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCollege" 
                class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>Year (required)<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlYear"
                class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can get values by ID which are different.

Comment: no i do repeat this control again and again and then dynamically i want to get all controls values

Comment: formatted html to be more readable